# Conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column filling an undefined datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im getting an error
Conversion of the varchar value '287201414153026341' overflowed an int column

But nothing I am doing in the sql is attempting to convert the value from its varchar column into an int.

```
Select * from  view_spotcheck_manager
```

That value is coming from a varchar column in the view called 'request_id"

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = @query;
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);


dt.Load(rdr);

rdr.Close();
return dt;
```

The Exception occurs on the line

```
dt.Load(rdr);
```

It seems apparent that for some reason the system is seeing that the value is all numbers and in spite of being a varchar column its attempting to convert it into an int without being instructed to so I am assuming some kind of default behavior in the Load() method.

Problem is I don't WANT it to do this I need it to be stay a varchar (in which case I shouldn't be getting this error. Short of constructing a strongly typed DataTable object and specifically loading each column is there any way to make the Load Method NOT convert this all numeric varchar value into int?..

Comment: The view may be calculating columns and, in the process, attempting a conversion that fails. Have a look at the definition of `view_spotcheck_manager` in the database.

Comment: So, if you run `Select * from  view_spotcheck_manager` in SSMS, you get no error at all?

Comment: What's the definition of the view, from what you have posted it looks conversion and overflow is happening in the view

Comment: Good call guys...turns out the column in question was mistakenly being linked on a join to an int column in another table.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out as the comments indicated the issue was in the underlying view not in the Load method.  the column in question was mistakenly being linked to an int column of another table. Fixed the join and all is working now.